# How can I mount internal ext4 drive as storage for Linux VirtualBox with Windows 10 host?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I have a Windows 10 host PC and a Linux Mint 18.2 virtual machine under Oracle VM VirtualBox (V 5.1.26r). The Windows OS and VirtualBox run from the same hard drive, and I would like to extend the ext4 storage of my virtual machine by enabling it use an additional ext4 formatted internal hard drive as storage. I was able to format the drive as ext4 under Windows using PartitionGuru, but how can I make this drive available as storage to my virtual machine? Note that I do not have space on the NTFS boot drive to add the ext4 drive as a Virtual Drive.

**EDIT:** Using Ext2Read in Windows I was able assign the ext4 drive a letter name. I was then able to use this drive as a shared folder in my Linux VirtualBox, but the problem here is that this changes all of the default Linux permissions, e.g., all text files become executable. How can I mount AND keep permission?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Direct disk access isn't for the faint of heart. See [here](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html), section 9.9.

> **Warning**
>
> Raw hard disk access is for **expert users only**. Incorrect use or use of
>   an outdated configuration can lead to total loss of data on the
>   physical disk. Most importantly, do not attempt to boot the partition
>   with the currently running host operating system in a guest. This will
>   lead to severe data corruption.

My advice is to format the internal hard disk in Windows as NTFS with the largest cluster size you can manage and assign to it a drive letter, say, G:.

Then, in VirtualBox, add a new hard disk file located on G:, with size equal to the free space available on it (or use a dynamic disk; performance impact isn't all that great, or so I found. Your mileage may vary).

Add the disk to the SATA controller of the Linux guest, and in Linux you'll find a new `/dev/sdb` disk ready to be fdisk'ed and made ready.

Comment: I'll let my work machine create the virtual disk file overnight and report back tomorrow. Thanks.

Comment: While trying to format the partition via mkfs.ext4, I get the this error: Host system reported disk full. VM execution is suspended. You can resume after freeing some space.

Error ID: DevAHCI_DISKFULL
Severity: Non-Fatal Error

Comment: So this solution works if you  leave space on the drive, i.e,. not making the VDI file as large as the drive.