# How do you use an existing ext4 hard drive with VirtualBox?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, hard-drive, virtualbox

I have an existing hard drive, an nvme drive with Ubuntu Linux on it. I have another nvme drive with Windows 10 that I use as my primary OS (games, web browsing, etc). While I *could* reboot between OSes in under a minute, I'd like the freedom to *not*. So, I wonder, can I "just" use my linux drive in Virtual Box? and boot virtual as well as boot for real? How would I set that up?

I *did* see from [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1247657/how-can-i-mount-internal-ext4-drive-as-storage-for-linux-virtualbox-with-windows) that the VirtualBox documentation has [some information on using "raw disks" as virtual storage (ch 9.7)](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html) -- but based on the format of the documentation, it somewhat looks like it either hasn't been updated in a while or potentially hasn't been a configuration often explored, so I worry about correctness and wonder if there are real world stories of success in this area

#### Update (2020-07-25)

After creating the VDMK via

```
# CWD: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox

VBoxManage.exe internalcommands createrawvmdk -filename "C:\Users\me\VirtualBox VMs\Ubuntu (local NVMe)\local-nvme.vmdk" -rawdisk \\.\PhysicalDrive1
```

And closing / exiting VirtualBox and related services and then starting the VBoxSVC.exe and VirtualBox.exe programs as an Administrator,

I'm getting an error:

```
The I/O cache encountered an error while updating data in medium "ahci-0-0" (rc=VERR_ACCESS_DENIED). Make sure there is enough free space on the disk and that the disk is working properly. Operation can be resumed afterwards.
```

I thought maybe that it'd be because the disk was currently online and needed to be offline, but I'm not seeing a way to offline the disk without additional errors
[image]

Disk 1 has an EFI Partition on it -- but it shouldn't anymore -- I used to dual boot with Ubuntu, so that 512MB partition *should* just be grub2.

*Note*: Disk 0 is my System Drive / the drive with Windows on it. Also, I do not currently use Grub for the boot loader.

Comment: Just import the physical machine into a virtual machine and use it that way.  https://www.joe0.com/2017/09/27/how-to-convert-physical-windows-computer-to-virtualbox-virtual-machine/

Comment: that creates an image of the real disk, rather than uses the real disk.

Comment: Yes, of course, but that will probably work much better.  That is how I use all my machines.

Comment: I don't have the space for that // that's not what I was asking. :-\

Comment: I did manage to find another article that confirms the instructions from the linked documentation https://www.serverwatch.com/server-tutorials/using-a-physical-hard-drive-with-a-virtualbox-vm.html

Comment: but it didn't seem to work -- when I go to add the drive in the VirtualBox UI the vdmk isn't shown as an option, and when I view "All files", an error occurs after selecting it

Comment: looks like a permissions issue actually ... hmm

Comment: running VirtualBox as an adminstration has resulted in "The I/O cache encountered an error while updating data in medium "ahci-0-0" (rc=VERR_ACCESS_DENIED). Make sure there is enough free space on the disk and that the disk is working properly. Operation can be resumed afterwards."

Comment: AFAIK Windows has some protection measures that prevent modification of data within a partition using the disk `\\.\PhysicalDrive?`. You may disable this protection by "unmounting" that drive - take it `offline` via diskpart as shown here: https://www.bankmark.de/virtualbox-and-raw-devices/

Comment: those are the steps I showed in the screenshot -- I can't offline the disk for some reason :(

Comment: found this: https://serverfault.com/questions/927845/cannot-set-secondary-hard-drive-offline-in-disk-management

looks like I might need to delete `/boot/EFI/Microsoft` on that partition

Comment: ok, so it turned out that deleting /boot/EFI/Microsoft had ... consequences. Fortunately, I found this article http://woshub.com/how-to-repair-deleted-efi-partition-in-windows-7/

which, in combo with gparted, I was able to re-create the EFI partition on my main disk and reinstall and configure the Microsoft Windows default EFI. 

I am now able to "offline" my linux disk within windows' diskpart tool

Comment: and after starting VirtualBox up again as an administrator, I can login to my raw disk linux :D

what an adventure!

Answer (score 2):

This was quite the adventure!

I'll try to break down my process here so it's a little easier to read than the comment thread above on the question.

### Step 1: Figure out the drive number of the raw disk you want to use

Two ways:

- Open "Disk Management", make note of the `Disk #` in the volume name column that represents the physical disk you want to use in VirtualBox
  [image: Windows 10 Disk Management Utility]

  For me, it happened to be `Disk 1`. Note that if the drive is currently mounted on your system the "Volume" column will likely show the partition *Label* instead of the `Disk # Partition #`.
- The other way is to open a command prompt (via `Windows`+`R` and typing `cmd` then pressing `Enter`) and running the `diskpart` command once the command prompt window opens. Windows will ask you if you want to allow the lprogram to run (standard administrative permission prompt). Once `diskpart.exe` opens its own window, you can run `list disk` to list your disks.
  [image: List item]

### Step 2: Create a virtual machine in virtual box, but without a hard drive

I named mine "Ubuntu (local NVMe)", located at the default location of

```
C:\Users\<UserFolder>\VirtualBox VMs\Ubuntu (local NVMe)\
```

More details at https://www.serverwatch.com/server-tutorials/using-a-physical-hard-drive-with-a-virtualbox-vm.html

### Step 3: Create a `vdmk` virtual disk file to use with Virtual Box

```
# CWD: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox

VBoxManage.exe internalcommands createrawvmdk -filename "C:\Users\<UserFolder>\VirtualBox VMs\Ubuntu (local NVMe)\local-nvme.vmdk" -rawdisk \\.\PhysicalDrive1
```

The import part here is the `\\.\PhysicalDrive1` at the end. Be sure that the number after `PhysicalDrive` matches the drive number you identified in step 1.

### Step 4: Close Virtual Box and re-open as an adminstrator

I do this via right clicking the quick shortcuts in the taskbar: [image]

### Step 5: Ensure that the rawdisk is "offline" / unmounted

Windows can't *really* control the disk while we're using it in virtual box, so we'll need to make sure it's offline.

1. run diskpart again
2. list disk
3. select disk 1 (or whichever number your disk is)
4. offline disk

This is part of where I ran in to an issue in the original question. I *couldn't* offline the disk because the disk had the Windows EFI partition on it.

The error read:

```
Disk attributes may not be changed on the current system disk or bios disk 0
```

How did this happen? I used to dual boot frequently, and a common strategy for managing multi-boot systems is to configure Grub (the default Ubuntu Linux boot loader) to be aware of all the other operating systems on the machine.

I first tried deleting the EFI/Microsoft folder in my Ubuntu drive's EFI partition -- turned out that was being used (as the error stated).

So, to restore the default Microsoft EFI partition, you'll need to follow this guide: http://woshub.com/how-to-repair-deleted-efi-partition-in-windows-7/

The tl;dr:

1. If an EFI partition doesn't exist, boot up a live gparted disk (or use gparted on your linux install on the other drive via reboot) and resize / make room for a 100MB fat32 partition
2. follow the rest of the instructions on the woshub.com link
3. You can now boot in to windows again!

Step 6: in Virtual Box, attach the vdmk to the new Virtual Machine

You may need to change the file browser to look at "All files" in order to see it

Comment: Thank you so much! I have been trying to do this for years and I finally got it working.

I had to follow additional steps found here: https://gist.github.com/neojp/3f9fef0b032b11e046696038f251e712